# Merging SVN dump file to fix broken repository

Tags: svn

One of our repositories appears to have become corrupt over the last couple of days. I'm not really sure what happened to it, just that it was suddenly complaining about files not existing within the repo, even though they were files added ages ago.

I ran a verify and the output is as such:

```
svnadmin: E160004: Corrupt representation '412 454 434 1049 (null) 69d49eee40d6ed46db3a7925d1f6b8bacb11e199 (null)'
svnadmin: E160004: Malformed representation header at F:/ShareCopies$/ICCServer01/svn/Repositories/VisaCardCless/db/revs/0/412:559
```

If I'm reading this correctly, the actual corruption lies between r412 and r559. The current revision is 672.

Now as luck would have it, I have a full dump of the repo before the corruption, but it only goes to r647 so we're missing a few commits there. I've verified this dump by loading it into a new repo and verifying it - came back clean.

So, theoretically, I have a clean dump up to r647 and I should be able to dump from r648 to r672 on the corrupt repo and then load that incremental backup back in. However, here is the stumbling block. When I try to dump 648 onwards, I get another corrupt representation error, this time saying it's at 567:1778. I don't know what this means, as the repo doesn't go beyond 672 so perhaps I'm reading the error message wrong. This does create a dump file but if I try to load it, I get a message about an unexpected end of file.

In any case, I'm a bit stuck as to how I could recover this repo in its entirety. Is there any dirty way to repair the corrupt database using the files from the good dump?

Comment: Try to get incremental dump starting from `-r 648:672` with svnrdump - it has more readable and human-friendly output for detecting broken-in-repo revisions

Comment: And **NEVER** use file:/// access to repositories on shared drives

Comment: Hi LAzy Badger, thanks for that. I've tried svnrdump and it's giving me an error as well: ra_serf: An error occurred during decompression.

Comment: On **which** revision exactly? You have to detect such breakpoints and avoid these revisions from dumping

Comment: Hi Lazy Badger, I wasn't really sure how to figure that part out but I've managed to fix my repository anyway. For some reason, even though dumping and reloading didn't work before, I've managed to make it work now. I've double and triple checked and even though I was doing the same things I was before, I now have a healthy repo. I will take your advice onboard about not using direct file paths though, I genuinely didn't realise that was an issue. Thank you for all your help!